cannot connect mariadb using express-mysql-session
I am trying to set up express-session, and I want to use mariaDB as a storage option, as my website already uses mariaDB for other storage in the backend.
In the readme of express-mysql-session, it says that it works with mariaDB npm express-mysql-session
I am using nodejs with express, express-session and mariaDB.
In my server file, I used it as it says in the readme:
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

const sessionOptions = {
    //connectionLimit: 10,
    host: process.env.MARIADB_HOST,
    port: process.env.MARIADB_PORT,
    user: process.env.MARIADB_USER,
    password: process.env.MARIADB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MARIADB_DATABASE,
    //createDatabaseTable: true
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(sessionOptions);
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name', // I dont know what this is for, I only included it because I hoped it might fix the issue :(
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { 
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: false, // set to true for production
        maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    }
}));

// Optionally use onReady() to get a promise that resolves when store is ready.
sessionStore.onReady().then(() => {
    // MySQL session store ready for use.
    console.log('MySQLStore ready');
}).catch(error => {
    // Something went wrong.
    console.error(error);
});

However, when I try to start my server, I get the following error:
Error: Server requests authentication using unknown plugin auth_gssapi_client. See TODO: add plugins doco here on how to configure or author authentication plugins.
    at PromisePool.query (C:\Users\femke\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:356:22)
    at C:\Users\femke\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:384:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLStore.query (C:\Users\femke\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:381:10)
    at C:\Users\femke\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:147:17 {
  code: 'AUTH_SWITCH_PLUGIN_ERROR',
  errno: undefined,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}

I changed the authentication method to gssapi, but that didnt help. Also, I still want to be able to authenticate using mysql_native_password, but when I try to change the plugin method like this:
ALTER USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('myPassword') OR gssapi;

and then type
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM user WHERE user = 'root' AND host = '127.0.0.1'

I only get mysql_native_password as plugin, even though users are supposed to be able to have more than one authentication method
and I have mariadb version 11.4.2.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or what I could do instead?
Thanks for your help!

Either you connect with root, and you mistyped password, or you do not have this user.  The second case is apparently interesting. There is design decision in MariaDB, is that if you're trying to connect with unknown user, it takes a random client definition, and plugin out of it, runs the authentication handshake, and makes it fail at the end. It fakes an existing user, so to say. The whole dance so it does not tell "this user does not exist", because it would be a security issue (telling too much), it emulates some existing user, as we see, rather poorly. There it is quite possible to randomly choose root with auth_gssapi . All in all, when you see this message is 99.99% giveaway for "this user does not exist". Not every design decision that looks good on paper is also good in practice.
The reason you do not see auth_gssapi in the mysql.user table is that mysql.user does not tell you the full truth. It is a VIEW, and user definitions are stored in mysql.global_priv, as JSON. All OR conditions are there. Also, know how user was defined, as SQL statement, SHOW CREATE USER is you friend.
You fix it by taking the hint, and using an existing user, probably with mysql_native_password authentication - I doubt that of whole multitude of MariaDB authentication plugins that driver will support anything else.

interestingly, I tried to go back to how my code was before I had the problem, and still get the same error, so I think that might be the case, even though I wonder how it is possible that I accidentally deleted the user...
I did have a look at the mysql.global_priv, thank you for that tip, and could see that I have different root users, one for the host localhost, one for 127.0.0.1 and one for my user I think, and there I could see that I have gssapi enabled in all three cases. Does that give me more information to work with? Because I think that does mean that the root user exists, does it?

If the user exists, and connecting via first plugin in user definition fails, the second plugin will  be tried. a connector can throw something like "unknown plugin" in this case. Which means, you might have mistyped the password.  For one of 3 root users (root@127.0.0.1, root@::1, and root@'%') ? I ,do not like this ambiguity, multiple users with the same name, so maybe it makes sense to keep their definitions/passwords in-sync, so it does not matter from which host you connect

Thank you very much for your help, I was not able to resolve the problem, so I reinstalled mariadb, imported a dump of my databases, and now everything works. I don't know why there were three root users, I think I did that accidentally when I set up the database. However, they all had the same password, and I know the password is correct, because I could use it to access the database. Thanks for your consideration!

ok this is emberassing but the error was.... I misspelled the env variable in the env file, I named it MARIADB_PASSSWORD... So it was exactly what you said
